# Text Randomizer Animation In Javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

Text inside buttons should change its letter randomly and come back to its normal text after a certain duration but when I hover the button the text is not stopping from randomizing and width of the button is changing. How do I fix the width and stop it from randomizing?

I think that there is a problem with getElementById part. In original code it was querySelector but that also doesn't seem to work

View this on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ishaan161028/pen/WNmbjOG)

HTML

```
        <div class="nav-buttons">
            <div class="btn1">
                <button>PROJECTS</button>
            </div>

            <div class="btn2">
                <button>
                    <span id="info-btn">INFO</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="theme-btn">
                <button onclick="changeClass()">Change Class</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
nav{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2em 4em;
}

.nav-buttons{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 2em;
}

button{
    position: relative;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid var(--secondary);
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: var(--secondary);
    font-family: Monorama;
    padding: 0.25em 0.75em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JavaScript

```
//Info Randomizer
const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

let interval = null;

document.getElementById("info-btn").onmouseover = event => {  
  let iteration = 0;
  
  clearInterval(interval);
  
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    event.target.innerText = event.target.innerText
      .split("")
      .map((letter, index) => {
        if(index < iteration) {
          return event.target.dataset.value[index];
        }
      
        return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)]
      })
      .join("");
    
    if(iteration >= event.target.dataset.value.length){ 
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    
    iteration += 1;
  }, 30);
}
```

Comment: `event.target.dataset.value` doesn't exist.  Check the console for errors.  Try adding a `data-value` attribute to the span.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the idea was to save the original text in the dataset and after randomization recover it. However, there were some problems with the logic (or syntax). I made this correction and increased the time to enhance the effect.

What causes the difference in the size of the element is that when the text changes, the space occupied also changes. To avoid this you can set a minimum size larger than expected even in the case where all letters are wide (generally W is the widest character). I decided to leave a fixed size of 175px. Alternatively you can use a monospace font so you have a consistent size in all cases and don't need to define a size.

```js
const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
let interval = null

document.querySelector("#info-btn").addEventListener("mouseover", event => {
    const targetElement = event.target
    let iteration = 0

    // stop old animation
    clearInterval(interval)

    // save the original text
    let originalText = targetElement.innerText
    targetElement.dataset.originalText = targetElement.dataset.originalText === undefined ? originalText : targetElement.dataset.originalText
    originalText = targetElement.dataset.originalText

    interval = setInterval(() => {
        const text = targetElement.innerText.split("").map((letter, index) => {
            if (index < iteration) {
                // restore original text
                return targetElement.dataset.originalText[index]
            }

            return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)]
        })

        targetElement.innerText = text.join("")

        if (iteration >= targetElement.dataset.originalText.length) {
            clearInterval(interval)
        }

        iteration += 1
    }, 150)
})
```

```css
nav {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2em 4em;
}

.nav-buttons {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 2em;
}

button {
    position: relative;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid var(--secondary);
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: var(--secondary);
    font-family: Monorama;
    padding: 0.25em 0.75em;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 175px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-buttons">
    <div class="btn1">
        <button>PROJECTS</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn2">
        <button>
            <span id="info-btn">INFORMATION</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="theme-btn">
        <button onclick="changeClass()">Change Class</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

my version of this code (modified) https://codepen.io/luis7lobo9b/pen/mdoypbq

Comment: Thanks! I added data-value to span class and it worked like a charm